# Combining different columns of characters from text files

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I have two files. I want to substitute the columns between characters 55 and 60 with another file, which has 5 characters on each line.

Can this be done with `awk` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most efficient method (it reads the first file twice), but it's simple.

```
paste -d'\0' <(cut -c1-54 file1) file2 <(cut -c61- file1) > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file1
```